# Jekyll Github Page post links open in new page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jekyll, liquid

When I write blog posts in Jekyll, I'm annoyed by the fact that in default, the post links which I created with markdowns open in the same window. So it brought my reader away from my site.

https://cecilialee.github.io/

Are there any ways, using either HTML, CSS, Liquid, or any other means to make the links in the post layout `target="_blank"` by default?

Answer (score 5):

I understand you want to insert external links into your posts which will open in a new tab.

That behaviour requires adding the `target="_blank"` attribute to the link element, and so browsers know to perform that behaviour.

At least in Kramdown, one of the more popular jekyll markdown flavours, I believe that can be done simply as follows:

```
[achorText](url){:target="_blank"}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I vote for this answer (^_^)v

reference from https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#links-and-images

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code to add attr for all the s tags OR specifically post a tags

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#link_other a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @JoostS mentioned, there is another option without jQuery:

Create a new file `_includes/new-window-fix.html` containing:

```html
<script>
    //open external links in a new window
    function external_new_window() {
        for(var c = document.getElementsByTagName("a"), a = 0;a < c.length;a++) {
            var b = c[a];
            if(b.getAttribute("href") && b.hostname !== location.hostname) {
                b.target = "_blank";
                b.rel = "noopener";
            }
        }
    }
    //open PDF links in a new window
    function pdf_new_window ()
    {
        if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return false;
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (var eleLink=0; eleLink < links.length; eleLink ++) {
        if ((links[eleLink].href.indexOf('.pdf') !== -1)||(links[eleLink].href.indexOf('.doc') !== -1)||(links[eleLink].href.indexOf('.docx') !== -1)) {
            links[eleLink].onclick =
            function() {
                window.open(this.href);
                return false;
            }
        }
        }
    } 
    pdf_new_window();
    external_new_window();
</script>
```

Then, modify the bottom of your layout document to include this new file:

```html
...
{% include new-window-fix.html %}
</body>
</html>
```

This solution was found on [jekyllcodex.org](https://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugin/new-window-fix/).